# 'livingdoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: specflow

I have already run `dotnet tool install --global SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI` to install specflow livingdoc.

[image]

then I run the command below:

[image]

But when I run `livingdoc test-assembly SpecFlowDemo.dll -t TestExecution.json`, I got this error `'livingdoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

[image]

and when I again `dotnet tool install --global SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI`, it shows below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved already after I run cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

After running

```
dotnet tool install --global SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI
```

Close and reopen the command prompt before running

```
livingdoc test-assembly SpecFlowDemo.dll -t TestExecution.json
```